# Submit form as soon as text field will get value by scanning bar code using Ruby on Rails 3

Tags: ruby, forms, ruby-on-rails-3

I have one doubt.I want when user will scan one bar code its value will fetch to one text field within one form.As soon as the bar code value will display on text-field that form should submit using Rails 3.I am explaining some codes below please help me to make it successfully.

## views/homes/index.html.erb

```
<%= form_for :hcsy,:url => {:action =>'scan_hcsy' } do |f| %>
    <%= f.text_field :reciept,placeholder:"Get your scan code"' %>
    <% end %>
```

## controller/homes_controller.rb

```
class HomesController < ApplicationController
    def index

    end
    def scan_hcsy

    end
end
```

Inside scan_hcsy action i will do some back-end application.Here only i need as soon as the text field will have the bar code value this form should submit.Please help me.

Comment: How the field is getting populated with value? JS
/AJAX or something? In that case you can submit form after populating field with js

Comment: Hi Raj,So how can i do that.Can you help me by giving one example ?

Comment: Show your js code which is populating the field

Comment: Raj I am not getting you properly.I dont have any any submit button once the text field will get some value the action "scan_hcsy" should excute in controller page.Thats only i need.

Comment: My question is: How your text field is getting populated?

Comment: It is getting value from a scanned barcode.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/75004/discussion-between-raj-and-rajat-474).